# how can i hide and show collaps

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i have two collaps in my page .i have Btn_First in collapsOne. when page is loaded , i wanna collapsOne will be appear and collapsTwo no . and when Btn_First clicked , collapsTwo will be appear. 
i did like below . all things are correct , i get Alert in MyFunc . but collapsTwo will not appear .

```
<div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
       <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data- parent="#checkout" href="#collapseOne"> First Step</a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse">
       <div class="accordion-inner">
          <form class="register-form">
             <input class="input-block-level" type="text" placeholder=" Name  " id="inputname">
             <input class="input-block-level" type="text" placeholder="Lname  " id="inputlname">
             <button class="btn btn- medium btn-general input-block-level" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" type="submit"  id="Btn_First" ">Run </button>
          </form>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 /////////////////

 <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
       <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#checkout" href="#collapseTwo"> First Step</a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse">
       <div class="accordion-inner">
          <form class="register-form">
              <input class="input-block-level" type="text" placeholder=" Email  " id="inputEmai;">
              <input class="input-block-level" type="text" placeholder="Phone  "  id="inputPhone">
              <button class="btn btn- medium btn-general input-block-level" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo" type="submit"  id="Btn_Second" ">Run </button>
         </form>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>

  ///////////////////

  <script type="text/javascript">
     $( document ).ready( function () {
        $("#collapseTwo").remove();
        $('#Btn_First).click(function () {
            if ( Mytemp == mytemp){ myfunc( 2 );}
        });
     )};
     function myfunc( flag ) {
        alert('hi');
     if ( flag == 2 ) {
        document.getElementById('collapseTwo').style.display = "visible";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure this is an MVC issue? It looks more like CSS/Boostrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function()
                   {
             $("#collapseTwo").hide();
                 $("#Btn_First").click(function()
          {
             GoFunc(2); 

               });

                    });

                      function Gofunc(2)
    {
     document.getElementById('collapseTwo').style.display = "block";  

    }

</script>
```

Comment: no i wanna check some condition in  $('#Btn_First).click(function () {}) and then go to MyFunc . i eddited $('#Btn_First).click(function () {})

Comment: i wanna go to MyFunc .

Comment: Why You are removing the CollapseTwo div ?   $("#collapseTwo").remove();
     Also Use Block for display property  .  document.getElementById('collapseTwo').style.display = "block";